# visual studio 2015 asp.net 5 aurelia, typescript compilation errors

Tags: typescript, aurelia

Im trying to get started with a asp.net 6 Aurelia project.
i did the following

1. installed `node` and `git` and added them to my path.
2. installed `jspm`
3. created a empty asp.net 5 project.
4. ran `jspm init` in the root of the web project, and specified `Enter server baseURL (public folder path) [./]:wwwroot`
5. ran `jspm install aurelia-bootstrapper`, `jspm install aurelia-framework`, `jspm install core-js`

now if i try to compile the project i get 106 TypeScript errors, it looks like a few .ts files where added under `wwwroot/jspm_packages/npm/...` and they don't compile.

Is there any way to tell the ts compiler to ignore those files?

the first 10 errors:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following article http://www.marwijnchristiaans.com/?p=6

Add the following files:

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  }
}
```

[es6.d.ts](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/louislewis2/AureliaDemo/master/src/AureliaDemo/scripts/typings/es6.d.ts)

core-js.d.ts

```
declare module 'core-js' {
    var core: any;
    export default core
}
```

Then it just worked!

Answer (score 1):

You must configure typescript compilation to exclude `wwwroot/jspm_packages`.  In your `tsconfig.json` add the following:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system"
  },
  "exclude": ["wwwroot/jspm_packages"]
}
```

Comment: also look at the sample app from aurelia.

Comment: @CallumLinington could you provide a link and also what do you want me to look at? (file, directory...?)

Comment: aurelia.io just look at the app, see how they constructed it, how they have configured it...

Comment: This was no good solution as it meant i would no longer get the meta data from the files in "wwwroot/jspm_packages"...

Comment: @partyelite check my other answer!